# NVIDIA card not working even after drivers installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to activate my NVIDIA graphics card  (GeForce GTX 1050) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. My laptop is Lenovo Legion Y530. I tried the installation of one the drivers from NVIDIA official website (nvidia-driver-415) and then rebooting my system. But this doesn't seem to work. When i try `nvidia-smi` in terminal it shows

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.27       Driver Version: 415.27       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2000MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

So I conclude that the card is off. Also when i try `nvidia-settings` it causes an error and shows the blank page. However if I try `sudo prime-select nvidia` it tells me that it has been already selected. So I'm completely stuck and don't know how to fic this problem.

Some of the background. I had troubles with Ubuntu installation before and switching to Intel Graphics card solved them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have similar problem with slightly different settings please any input will be greatly appreciated https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332114/not-detected-second-screen-after-update-quadro-rtx-3000-mobile-lenovo-hinkpad

Answer (score 0):

I have a GTX 1050 Ti and it works well on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Note: these steps are for a desktop with an aftermarket video card installed. If your laptop has a more complicated configuration, this may not be the proper process.

The following steps will purge the incorrect driver, add a ppa with more recent versions of the driver, and install it.  You will end up with the 390 driver, which is what you want.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 nvidia-settings
```

This worked for me both on my original Ubuntu 18.04 install and now on the 18.04.2 HWE kernel.

You might be able to install `nvidia-390`, but that is not what I did.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I’ve tried to follow this steps but after that Ubuntu doesn’t launch.

Comment: I am sorry it didn't work for you.  Your laptop must be set up differently than my pc.

Comment: I have similar problem with slightly different settings please any input will be greatly appreciated https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332114/not-detected-second-screen-after-update-quadro-rtx-3000-mobile-lenovo-hinkpad

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue please try disabling secure boot in case of dual boot or changing the drivers to go with xorg ones. Hope it helps: [Not detected second screen after update, Quadro RTX 3000 Mobile , Lenovo hinkpad p15 g1, Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332114/not-detected-second-screen-after-update-quadro-rtx-3000-mobile-lenovo-hinkpad/1332134#1332134)